# ORDS: The username or password for the connection pool named |default|lo|, are invalid, expired, or the account is locked

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords

The username or password for the connection pool named |default|lo|, are invalid, expired, or the account is locked

I have followed all the process in this tutorial(https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/06/how-to-update-the-ords_public_user-password/), but still no solution. I have make sured that all the user accounts (APEX_PUBLIC_USER, ORDS_PUBLIC_USER e.t.c) are not locked but still no solution.

Comment: See if this helps https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2023/01/troubleshooting-ords-startup-errors-the-pool-is-invalid/